# Intent does not carry over to next activity, something small missing

Tags: android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

I've used stack-overflow to pass the adapter position from my Events Page using Firebase Recycler View to my Detailed view so I can show just that event, however the code I've written doesn't seem to work.

I'm sure it's correct but i've missed something obvious.

Here is my MainActivity

public class EventsDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView mRecylerView;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private EditText mSearch;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Events, EventsDisplayActivity.EventsViewHolder> mEventsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_display);

    setTitle("Events");

    //"Events" here will reflect what you have called your database in Firebase.
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mRecylerView = findViewById(R.id.result_list);
    mSearch = findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);




    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
    Query query = dbRef.orderByKey();
    //Query search = dbRef.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    mRecylerView.hasFixedSize();
    mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Events>().setQuery(query, Events.class).build();

    mEventsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Events, EventsDisplayActivity.EventsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(EventsViewHolder holder, final int position, final Events model) {
            holder.setName(model.getName());
            holder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            holder.setImage(getBaseContext(), model.getImage());
        }

        @Override
        public EventsDisplayActivity.EventsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.event_list, parent, false);

            return new EventsDisplayActivity.EventsViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    mRecylerView.setAdapter(mEventsAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mEventsAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mEventsAdapter.stopListening();


}

public static class EventsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public EventsViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setName(String title){
        TextView post_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setDescription(String desc){
        TextView post_desc = mView.findViewById(R.id.event_desc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }
    public void setImage(Context context, String image){
        ImageView post_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.event_image);
        Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(post_image);
    }
}
```

}

And here is the detailed activity which for some reason is not getting the Intent.

public class EventDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "position";
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mEventReference;
private ValueEventListener mEventListener;
private String mEventKey;

private TextView mDetailName;
private TextView mDetailDesc;
private ImageView mDetailImage;
private static final String TAG = "EventDetailActivity";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_detail);

    //Getting the selected event from intent
    mEventKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POSITION);
    if(mEventKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POSITION");
    }
    //Init the DB
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child(mEventKey);
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);


    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    // Set title of Detail page
    // collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.item_title));

    //Init Views
    mDetailName = findViewById(R.id.event_title_detail);
    mDetailDesc = findViewById(R.id.event_desc_detail);
    mDetailImage = findViewById(R.id.event_image_detail);
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Event Listener to the view
    // [Start event_value_event_listener]
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Event Object and use the values to update said UI
            Events events = dataSnapshot.getValue(Events.class);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            mDetailName.setText(events.name);
            mDetailDesc.setText(events.description);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Toast.makeText(EventDetailActivity.this, "Failed to load events.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

        }
    };
    mEventReference.addValueEventListener(eventListener);
    // [END post_value_event_listener]

    // Keep copy of post listener so we can remove it when app stops
    mEventListener = eventListener;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Remove post value event listener
    if (mEventListener != null) {
        mEventReference.removeEventListener(mEventListener);
    }
}
```

}

Appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try to debug and set a breakpoint at this line?
`intent.putExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());`

Just to check the value of `getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: It gives the listed result 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into a new question. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several problems with this code.

Firstly, the Adapter started counting at 0, but my database started at 1. So I made a small work-around for the time-being and will order my database at a later date.

```
intent.putExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition() +1));
```

I needed to force the context into a string on the main event activity.

Finally, using Log.d, I checked if I was getting the result I needed and it turned out it worked okay!

```
String mEventKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POSITION);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: current event number is: " + mEventKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, it seems correct, the only remark I have is that `RecyclerView.ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` returns an Integer primitive, not a string.

So in this case, in your detail activity, the code to retrieve the intent should actually be:

```
mEventKey = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
```

Where `0` is a default value in case `EXTRA_POSITION` was not set.

Here are the official docs on `Intent.getIntExtra`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getIntExtra

Comment: Hi, Firstly thanks for taking a look. I thought as much 

I've got it working with the ammended code (see my main post edit) but now I get this error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.drycapp.finalyearapp/com.drycapp.finalyearapp.EventDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post another question for that issue, it is not related to this question (check the title again).
Also, please accept the answer if it was the right one.

Comment: I didn't change the question, I just updated the code with your suggestions which still does not fix the problem. In-fact, your input was helpful to steer me into the correct idea but was in fact wrong.

Comment: I can see the change, and I see what you changed, and it changes the question.